# Assigning an array reference to another array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
int a[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int b[]={4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

a=b;

System.out.println("a[0] = "+a[0]);
```

This displays `a[0] = 4` as obvious because `a` is assigned a reference to `b`.

---

If it is modified as follows

```
int a[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int b[]={4, 3, 2, 1, 0};        

System.out.println("a[(a=b)[0]] = "+a[(a=b)[0]]);  //<-------
```

then, it displays `a[(a=b)[0]] = 5`.

---

Why doesn't this expression - `a[(a=b)[0]]` yield `4`, the 0<sup>th</sup> element of `b` even though it appears to be the same as the previous case?

Comment: Array index has the [highest priority](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second expression features an assignment expression inside an array indexer expression. The expression evaluates as follows:

- The target of the indexer expression is selected. That's the *original* array `a`
- The index expression is evaluated by first assigning `b` to `a`, and then taking the element of `b` at index zero
- The index of the outer indexer is evaluated as `b[0]`
- The index is applied to `a`, returning `5`
- The assignment of `b` to `a` takes effect. Subsequent accesses to `a[i]` will reference `b`, not the original `a`.

Essentially, your single-line expression is equivalent to this two-line snippet:

```
System.out.println("a[(a=b)[0]] = "+a[b[0]]); // Array reference completes first
a=b;                                       // Array assignment is completed last
```

Comment: so in the end its nothing but a[4]..:)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, but why assignment of b to a takes effect only at the end of the process?

Comment: @AlexR It does not matter when the assignment actually happens in order to decide what's the outcome of the expression `a[something]` is going to be. The only thing that matters is what object is picked as the first operand of the `[]` expression. In this example, the object is the old `a`, because the assignment is to the right of the operand, so the assignment's effect is not visible at that point of the expression.