# The following java code is giving output 1 2 3 .How the code is executed?

Tags: java, arrays

How in this code for loop is running three times, as here argcopy array size is 2 and as per my knowledge once an array is created its size can't be changed.

```
class test {                                     //line 1
    public static void main(String[] args) {     //line 2
        String[][] argcopy = new String[2][2];   //line 3
        String arg[] = new String[3];            //line 4
        int x;                                   //line 5
        arg[0] = "1";                            //line 6
        arg[1] = "2";                            //line 7
        arg[2] = "3";                            //line 8
        argcopy[0] = arg;                        //line 9
        x = argcopy[0].length;                   //line 10
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
        {
            System.out.println(" " + argcopy[0][y]);   //line 11
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning an array reference to another array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348005/assigning-an-array-reference-to-another-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2D array is simply an array of arrays.  This means you don't even have to allocate storage for the `second dimension`.  This also permits you to have ragged arrays which is demonstrated below.

```java
      int[][] raggedArray = new int[5][];
      raggedArray[0] = new int[]{1,2,3};
      raggedArray[1] = new int[]{4,5,6,7,8,9};
      raggedArray[2] = new int[]{10,12,13,14};
      raggedArray[3] = new int[]{15};
      raggedArray[4] = new int[]{16,17,18,19,20};
      for (int[] array : raggedArray) {
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
      }
```

Each new array is simply an `object` which is assigned to the desired location.

Comment: That was an mistake.Sorry bro.

Comment: Quite alright.  It's not really a problem if someone provides one that does a better job of answering your question.  I just wanted to know why so I could improve my responses in the future.  After all that is why we participate on this site.

Comment: No brother your explanation was quite good, i learnt in one go.Great job keep it up.

Answer (score 4):

> once an array is created its size can't be changed

That's true, but `argcopy[0]` is a reference to a `String[]` (a `String` array).

When you assign to it:

```
argcopy[0] = arg;
```

It references a different array than the one it originally referenced. While the original array it referenced had a length of `2`, the new array it references has a length of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `argcopy[0] = arg;` sets the array `arg` as the first element of the array `argcopy`.

The line `x = argcopy[0].length;` sets the `length` of the first element of array `argcopy` in variable `x`. So now variable `x` has a value `3`.
Since you tested the loop with `y < x`, the loop will run three times.