# Reference to another array by index

Tags: java, reference

Is it possible to somehow get reference of one array by indexes in java like this pseudocode, for example:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] // size 8
array2 = [] // size 4
for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i ++)
{
  array2[i] = reference to array1[random(0,3)]
}
```

so for example random numbers were 3 0 4 6

```
array2[0] = array1[3]
array2[1] = array1[0]
```

and if you change `array2[0]` to `99` then `array1[3]= 99` as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning an array reference to another array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348005/assigning-an-array-reference-to-another-array-in-java)

Comment: Why would `random(0,3)` generate 6 as a random number? That's outside the 0-3 range.

Comment: No, it is not possible to "link" array cells like that. What you need to a class wrapping the array(s), so that code in the `set()` method can perform the appropriate update.

Comment: It is not possible to do this .

Comment: Being ripe for race conditions aside, you'll either end up having to update multiple arrays, or you'll have to return array copies (not modifiable by reference). Short of `misc.Unsafe`/jni, you can't really just have an array pointing to anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly possible, but you can fake it:

```
class Reference {

    private Object value;

    public Reference(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }

    public static Reference[] ofInts(int[] items) {
        Reference[] ret = new Reference[items.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            ret[i] = new Reference(items[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
int array1[] = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
Reference refArray1[] = Reference.ofInts(array1);

final int arr2Size = 4;
Reference refArray2[] = new Reference[arr2Size];
Random rand = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < arr2Size; ++i) {
    int index = rand.nextInt(array1.length);
    refArray2[i] = refArray1[index];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(refArray1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(refArray2));
System.out.println("---");

refArray2[0].setValue(99); // set reference value

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(refArray1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(refArray2));
```

Sample output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[4, 6, 3, 3]
---
[1, 2, 3, 99, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[99, 6, 3, 3]
```